# calculating total login-logout time of a particular user in mysql

Tags: mysql

mysql> select * from timing;

```
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| employeeIdNo | employeeLogTime     | employeeLogType |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|            1 | 2011-08-16 09:53:29 | login           |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 10:45:42 | logout          |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 10:55:29 | login           |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 17:55:39 | logout          |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

i want to display the total working time of employee using above data. so i want a mysql query to calculate the total time of employeeIdNo=1. my table name is timing and employeeIdNo is the foreign key references from table employee. after calculation it should return me the totalLogTime value = 7:52:23. please provide me with appropriate query. thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far? This is the question!

Comment: If you restructured the data so that it is in the form (SessionID, EmployeeID, LoginTime, LogoutTime) then the query becomes very easy and you haven't actually lost any data.

Comment: Any chance that a user can login twice, maybe by using a second client to start a second session? In that case you'd *have* to store sessionID in order to find the correct pairs of login/logout timestamps.

Comment: i didnt get the restructuring part. basically there r many employees who login and logout. the above is a small part of database.

Comment: no the system is like, when a user enters his username and password, he is validated and checked if he is loggin in for first time, if yes, employeeLogTime is stored and EmployeeLogType is set to "login", and if second time that user again logs in with his username and password, he is validated and this time he is already logged in so, employeeLogTime is stored and employeeLogType is stored as "logout". the process continues for many users. m tryin to make a attendance system.

Comment: If the session expires, or the server crashes you update the logout time ?

Answer (score 1):

a'r's recommendation makes a lot of sense. Also calculating the duration for each session at logout is a much better approach - although this is not strictly normalized, it spreads the load of calculating....

```
SELECT ilv.employee, 
SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logouttime) 
  - IF(logintime IS NULL, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logouttime), 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logintime)))
FROM (
    SELECT a.employeeId, a.time AS logouttime,
    (SELECT MAX(b.time)
      FROM log b
      WHERE b.employeeId=a.employeeId
      AND b.time<a.time
      AND b.type='login')  as logintime
    FROM log a 
    WHERE a.type='logout'
    AND a.time BETWEEN <range start> AND <range end>
    AND employeeId=1 /* optional */
) ilv
GROUP BY ilv.employeeId
```